# How can I set the coordinate interval in DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot 100 points in a density plot, but don't know how to set the interval of the x and y range.

My  code is:

```
DensityPlot[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]
```

Comment: does `n = 100;
ListDensityPlot[
 Table[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y], {y, -3, 3, 6/(n - 1)}, {x, -3, 3, 
   6/(n - 1)}], ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
 DataRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]` give what you need?

Answer (score 4):

Functions like `Plot` and `DensityPlot` normally try to adaptively find a good step size to visualize the function. If you want a plot that simply uses a grid of equally spaced points, you can use the `PlotPoints -> n` and `MaxRecursion -> 0` options:

```
DensityPlot[y + Sin[x^2 + 3 y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
 PlotPoints -> 10,
 MaxRecursion -> 0
]
```

Setting `MaxRecursion -> 0` tells the plotting function to not refine the initial 10 points in the grid.